# Tkinter is not working in windows 10 computer

Tags: python, tkinter

The program:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

error for this program:

```
c:/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/python/tkinter.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\python\tkinter.py", line 1, in <module>     
    from tkinter import *
  File "c:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\python\tkinter.py", line 3, in <module>     
    root = Tk()
NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined
```

is the problem I am still facing in my computer. please help me to rectify this error

Comment: Don't name your file `tkinter.py`. Name it something like `GUI.py`

Comment: In other words: you're importing your own file.

Comment: You have named your file ```tkinter.py```. instead of fetching from the real tkinter folder, it is trying to fetch ```Tk``` from your file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Tkinter Tk is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616501/python-tkinter-tk-is-not-defined)